# Como crear ejecutable con Pyinstaller para un programa que toma archivos desde una carpeta?

Tags: python, script, pyinstaller

He creado un script .py que contiene una carpeta donde guardo archivos XML y los analizo en busqueda de información para guardar esos datos dentro de 2 archivos .txt que muestran los resultados.
He generado un .exe con Pyinstaller pero necesito que incluya los archivos .txt y que me permita agregar o quitar archivos de la carpeta antes mencionada para ser analizados en cada ejecución.

Esta es la estructura de mi proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En amarillo esta marcada la carpeta desde la que tomo los archivos para analizar
En rojo los txt sobre los cuales guardo la info que necesito

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada verifica si al ejecutar tu programa generado con pyinstaller los archivos quedan residentes en alguna carpeta temporal. Haz una búsqueda a nivel sistema operativo.

Para poder hallar los archivos en carpetas temporales deberás impedir que el programa Python finalice. Pon una pausa en el programa de ser necesario.

Luego cuéntanos si los archivos buscados están o no en alguna carpeta temporal de tu equipo

Answer (score 0):

He solucionado el inconveniente moviendo los archivos y carpetas a la raiz del directorio dist que genera Pyinstaller.

Muchas gracias por la respuesta!!